# npm ERR! 415 Unsupported Media Type - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/reddwarf-root - Hard link is not allowed

Tags: node.js, npm

when I using this github actions to publish the npm package with mono project structure:

```
  - uses: JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v2
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.RDJS_NPM_TOKEN }}
```

shows error:

```
Run JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v2
Error: NpmCallError: Call to "npm publish" exited with non-zero exit code 1
npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! code E415
npm ERR! 415 Unsupported Media Type - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/reddwarf-root - Hard link is not allowed
{
  "error": {
    "code": "E415",
    "summary": "415 Unsupported Media Type - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/reddwarf-root - Hard link is not allowed",
    "detail": ""
  }
}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-10-18T12_18_19_247Z-debug-0.log
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this error? This is the root package.json look like:

```
{
    "name": "reddwarf-root",
    "private": false,
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/*"
    ],
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS",
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "commitlint": {
        "extends": [
            "@commitlint/config-conventional"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "lerna run build",
        "clean": "lerna run clean",
        "lint:spelling": "lerna run lint:spelling",
        "lint:es": "lerna run lint:es",
        "lint:ts": "lerna run lint:ts",
        "test": "lerna run test",
        "prerelease": "lerna run build",
        "release": "changeset publish"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@changesets/cli": "^2.14.1",
        "@commitlint/cli": "^12.0.1",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^12.0.1",
        "@antfu/eslint-config": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/types": "^4.18.0",
        "cspell": "^5.3.7",
        "eslint": "^7.22.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-compat": "^3.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2",
        "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-padding": "^0.0.4",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-tsdoc": "^0.2.11",
        "husky": "=5",
        "lerna": "^4.0.0",
        "lint-staged": ">=10",
        "prettier": "2.2.1"
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix"
    }
}
```